# Active Admin and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin, nested-attributes

It's been a while since I have done anything with Rails and now I'm using rails 4. Also I'm taking a look at active admin. Looking for a little assistance to get me on my way.

I have two models:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  attr_accessible :membership_type
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
  attr_accessible :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street,   :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email, :membership_attributes
end
```

The idea her is that when creating a new member you should be able to select a membership type form a drop down (there are 3 options)

My active admin resource look like this at the moment but I need to incorporate the new membership type:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member do
  # Set Which Columns are to be displayed on the index page
  index do
    column :forename
    column :middlename
    column :surname
    column :house_no
    column :house_name
    column :street
    column :town
    column :postcode
    column :home_tel
    column :mobile_tel
    column :work_tel
    column :email
    default_actions
  end

  # Set Which Columns are to be displayed on Create New Member
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Member Registration" do
    f.input :forename
    f.input :middlename
    f.input :surname
    f.input :house_no
    f.input :house_name
    f.input :street
    f.input :town
    f.input :postcode
    f.input :home_tel
    f.input :mobile_tel
    f.input :work_tel
    f.input :email
    f.input :memberships, :label => 'Membership Type', :as => :select, :collection => Membership.all
  end   
end
```

So my memberships select box appears in the form but is showing as:

```
#<Membership:123456>
```

How do I get it to show the actual value?

Also slightly off the question topic but with rails 4 I no longer have to use `attr_accessible` do I, but for now I've included the gem 'protected_attributes'. Any pointers on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails 4 and are just starting out with ActiveAdmin, I would recommend using the version from master branch. ActiveAdmin < 1.0.0-pre does not support Rails 4, and actually supports strong parameters via the `permit_params` dsl.

To use that version, add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

In Rails 4, you won't be using `attr_accessible` anymore, and all your params will need to be permitted in the controller. Check the docs here for details:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member do
  permit_params :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email, membership_ids
end
```

As for your membership not displaying properly, ActiveAdmin does at smart-lookup to try to determine the display name for something, trying for a method named `name`, `title`, `display_name`, `to_label`, to_s`, and, I think,`inspect` if all else fails. Simply add a method to your membership model:

```
def display_name
  membership_type
end
```

Comment: Search for `display_name_methods` in the ActiveAdmin code base to get the current list and order: `:display_name`, `:full_name`, `:name`, `:username`, `:login`, `:title`, `:email`, `:to_s`

Answer (score 2):

To show membership in column view you can do something like this:

```
column :memberships do |member| 
  member.memberships.map { |ms| ms.type }.join(', ')
end
```

In Rails 4 instead of using the 'protected_attributes' gem you can put this code in the Active Admin initializer (active_admin.rb):

```
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
# Allow ActiveAdmin admins to freely mass-assign when using strong_parameters
  [(params[resource_request_name] || params[resource_instance_name]).try(:permit!) || {}]
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, though it seems as if im not creating my member correctly, i understand what your doing in the answer, but when i create a member the params being passed are member[membership_ids][]:Student for example, shouldnt this be member[membership_type][]:Student, bit lost here

Comment: This sounds to me like you are actually looking to have a 1 to 1 relationship between Member and Membership. This would require to declare the association in Member as has_one :membership.But if that's the case and Membership has only the field membership_type do you actually need the association? Perhaps you could just add the field membership_type to the Member model?

Comment: well there are 3 membership_types, and yes a member can only have one of these, so a 1 to 1 is best then?

Comment: If Membership has only the field membership_type and your are not planning to add more fields i'd just add this field to the Member model and skip Membership and the association altogether. Otherwise it should be a 1 to 1 relationship, i guess.

Answer (score 2):

To show the actual membership type's value use this,

```
f.input :memberships, :label => 'Membership Type', :member_label => :membership_type
```

Formtastic [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/RadioInput) has more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Looks every thing fine, there is small typo in attr_accessible:

```
:membership_attributes -> :memberships_attributes
```

if possible put it at first place,

```
attr_accessible :memberships_attributes, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street,   :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email
```

To allow the nesting and the updating of has_many associations you must add the following to the model that they belong to :

1. Add an attr_accessible for the nested attribute to allow for mass assignment.
2. Add the obvious has_many association with the option to destroy the related has_many associations if the belongs_to model is destroyed.
3. Add the accepts_nested_attributes to allow a single request to update the has_many model/s and the belongs_to model with the option to destroy the has_many model if requested.

Comment: hi @PravinMishra, thanks for the advice, why is it it plural though? as in memberships? also any idea on how to get the value to show in the column view, ive added column :memberships but it just shows the text 'Membership'. its like the value hasnt been passed through

Comment: @Richlewis member has many memberships, So your code going to access memberships attributes not membership attributes. Member model will have relation with memberships only :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

```
f.input :memberships, :label => 'Membership Type', :as => :select,:collection => proc {(Membership.all).map{|m| [t.membership.name,t.id]}}
```